# Bokeh Plots: Change line plot by selected bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I've been searching on for a bit and haven't found an answer that works yet so I figured I'd ask.

**Question**

Everything works to spec except when I click on the statesbp hbar plot, I can't seem to fire off a calback function (hbar_select in this case) that gets the value of the selected bar. I added a print statement into the callback function, and I don't see this fire off in my terminal when the server is running.

What will i need to do to get the selection of bar chart through a callback?

Thanks in advance,

Rich

```
hbar_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(state=[], sessions=[],))
hbartools = 'tap'
statesbp = figure(y_range=state_data.sort_values('sessions')['state'].values,plot_width=300,plot_height=500, tools='tap', title='Sessions By State')
statesbp.x_range.start = 0
statesbp.hbar(y='state', right='sessions', height=.5, color='navy', source=hbar_source)

def update(selected=None):
    data = get_data(state=selected)
    source.data = source.from_df(data)
    source_static.data = source.data
    ts1.title.text = selected

def hbar_select(attrname, old, new):
    index_of_selected = new['1d']['indices'][0]
    print(index_of_selected)
    update(selected = index_of_selected)

def update_hbar():
    data = get_states()
    hbar_source.data = hbar_source.from_df(data)


#on hbar select, update line chart
hbar_source.on_change('selected',hbar_select)

# initialize data
update()
update_hbar()

curdoc().add_root(series)
curdoc().title = "Website Visits"
```

[Bokeh working plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh8uh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are looking for changes in `hbar_source.selected` but this won't change, it will always be an Selection object! You should change this line to `hbar_source.selected.on_change('indices',hbar_select)`. This will change when you select a bar to the index of the bar in the `ColumnDataSource`.

Comment: Worked like a charm Thank You.